# Removing footer and including filename as a column in U-SQL

Tags: azure, csv, u-sql

There are expense files(CSV format) from different business units, with header and footer in it. The files are of different names Expense__YYYYMMDD.csv

I have the below requirements to address in U-SQL.

1. Remove header and footer. I use SkipNRows:1 to skip the header. I couldn't find any option to exclude the footer. Had a look at the "Silent" parameter, but it would by-pass the encoding errors(if any) as per the documentation.
   Is there any other parameter/way that I could use to exclude the filter.

The file structure is as follows:

```
1   ACTUAL  1/03/2018   SourceSystem12  BUNIT3                          
2   00900_AB    H6720180205gv   1   1/03/2018   XYZ 1000004 4500532 Imogen      userid1 2/03/2018
2   00900_AB    H6720180205ub   1   1/03/2018   XYZ 1000004 4500532 Imogen1     userid2 2/03/2018
2   00900_AB    H6720180205wp   1   1/03/2018   XYZ 1000004 4500532 Imogen      userid1 2/03/2018
2   00900_AB    H6720180205yc   1   1/03/2018   XYZ 1000004 4500532 Imogen      userid2 2/03/2018
9   90  532 68060.24    62916.75    5143.49 BUnit3  1/03/2018   BUMonthYear
```

Also, the *header and footer have less number of columns than the actual data*.

2. I need to consolidate all these files into a single file before storing it in DatalakeAnalytics. As part of the aggregation, businessunit from the file name should be included as one of the columns in the final output file.

   Eg., 
    If there are 2 source files of same structure with different file names as below

   ```
   Expense_HR_20180801.csv
   ```

   Column1, column2, column3

   ```
   Expense_IT_20180801.csv
   ```

   column1, column2, column3

   The final output file should be:

   ```
   Expense_20180801.csv
   ```

   Businessunit, column1,column2,column3

Any suggestions/guidance on

```
   a. how to remove the footer from the individual CSVs, and 
   b. how to extract the businessunit from the filename and include it as one of the columns is much appreciated.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anything in the text of the footer that can identify it as one?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first column is a descriptor for the row type, where 1 is header, 2 is main data and 9 is footer.  One approach to this is to import the data as a single row using a delimiter that does not exist in the data, then remove rows you don't need, eg using .net string methods like `StartsWith`.  The [virtual columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/input-files-u-sql) feature of U-SQL easily allows you to incorporate parts of the filename into your rowset.  Here's a simple example:

```
// Import the file as one column, clean out the header and foot, then output again
DECLARE @inputFile string = @"\input\Expense_{businessUnit}_20180801.csv";

@input =
    EXTRACT col1 string,
            businessUnit string
    FROM @inputFile
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '†');


@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @input
    WHERE NOT col1.StartsWith("1 ")
      AND NOT col1.StartsWith("9 ");


OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

My results:

[image: My results]

Now the file is clean, you can import using normal methods.

Answer (score 0):

for your second issue, you should use virtual columns check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523207/u-sql-get-file-paths-from-pattern) solution.

for your first issue, maybe you should try to create custom extractor if you know footer pattern, then in extractor logic, you can remove the footer. 
If you can provide more information about file and footer so we can give you more precisely potential solution/fix/idea :)

Comment: thanks, was able to handle the second issue. Have added a sample file structure.